# Outlook send emails to different people on a schedule

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, scheduled-tasks

I have this excel file schedule and I need to send the exact same email to the people on the list, when the day is correct. so email Person 1 on the 1st April etc.

The email will be the same, however if it can be like mail merge where it says Dear Person 1, that'd be great, but the main thing is to send the email according to the schedule.

```
Day to send     Who to
01/04/2018      Person 1
02/04/2018      Person 2
03/04/2018      Person 3
04/04/2018      Person 4
05/04/2018      Person 5
06/04/2018      Person 6
07/04/2018      Person 7
08/04/2018      Person 8
09/04/2018      Person 1
```

Thanks for the help,

Comment: I've tried mail merge, but that just sends out all the emails at once. I can delay sending of the mail merge, but again, after the time elapses, the emails all get sent at once. The only other thing i can think of is just queue up a years worth of emails then manually delay sending of each email by the required amount.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it in Excel and VBA.

```
Name    Date    Email


Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application


Msg = "message"
Subj = "subject  " + Format(Date, "mmmm yyyy")
EmailAddr = "a@a.com"

Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With MItem
    .To = EmailAddr
    .Subject = Subj
    .Body = Msg
    .Display
    .Send
End With
```